# How to prevent clang-format to modify the CMake substitution strings?

Tags: cmake, clang-format

Let be the file Version.h.in that we will "configure" in CMake :

```
configure_file("Version.h.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Version.h" @ONLY)
```

In this file I have CMake variables such as :

```
#define HELLO_VERSION_MAJOR @VERSION_MAJOR@
```

And clang-format puts a space before the last '@' :

```
#define HELLO_VERSION_MAJOR @VERSION_MAJOR @
```

What rule should I modify to prevent this ?

Comment: Why do you run the clang-formant on *.in files ?

Comment: Because this is the file that ends up in git and I want it to be properly formatted. The generated file exists only in the build directory.

Answer (score 2):

`clang-format` can be told to skip code like this:

```
int formatted_code;
// clang-format off
    void    unformatted_code  ;
// clang-format on
void formatted_code_again;
```

This was added atleast 6 months ago. multi-line comments can be used too (and that way only a part of a line can be skipped)

```
int /* clang-format off */ a    /* clang-format on */ = 5;
```

see [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more options.