# stopping clang-format to modify the CMake substitution strings?

Tags: cmake, clang-format

I have different projects using a CMake template to propagate some info from the `CMakeList.txt` into the `.cpp`/`.h` files.

CMake use replacement strings sandwiched between `@`.
Example (in `MyAppConfig.in.h`):

```
#define MY_APP_VERSION  @MyApp_VERSION_MAJOR@
```

Now if I have a project with name MyApp in `CMakeLists.txt`
I add:

```
configure_file(MyAppConfig.in.h MyAppConfig.h)
```

And a `MyAppConfig.h` will be generated with `MY_APP_VERSION` defined as my major project version.

This is standard CMake stuff as far as I know.

Now we started using clang-format lately and it keeps adding a space between the last `@` and the preceding character
we end up with:

```
#define MY_APP_VERSION  @MyApp_VERSION_MAJOR @
```

Now we've added the proper "// clang-format off & on" to those files.

Is there another way, like an option to add to `.clang-format`?
I looked for it but could not find any!

the question has been asked 8 years ago, and the only solution at the time was to add the "// clang-format off|on".

Also, I'd like to understand why clang-format does it, it is not a proper identifier, so why try to format it?

I looked at:

[How to prevent clang-format to modify the CMake substitution strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397250/how-to-prevent-clang-format-to-modify-the-cmake-substitution-strings)

and I looked at:

https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

for an option.

Answer (score 0):

A **template** for a file in some programming language generally doesn't fit for that programming language. So running language-specific formatters for a template file has a little sense.

Your problem is that you name your template file `MyAppConfig.in.h` in the way, how C/C++ headers are named, with `.h` at the end. For that reason `clang-format` utility attempts to interpret this file as a C/C++ one.

Just **rename** the file to `MyAppConfig.h.in` (with `.in` at the end), so `clang-format` wouldn't inspect that file and wouldn't modify it.

---

A rule of thumb: `foo.in` is a template for `foo`.

That is, the extension `.in` should be added **after all** other file's extensions.

Comment: yes, make sense and it is the solution I was already thinking about
Thanks for your input